# Wildfly 15 Undertow permanent redirect

Tags: redirect, jboss, wildfly, http-status-code-301, undertow

I created a undertow-handlers.conf in my WEB-INF folder.

I added a bunch of rows like this:

```
regex('/foo') -> redirect('/bar');
```

That works as expected, redirecting all requests of /foo to /bar.

Unfortunately, the response code is 302 (moved temporarily).

I need it to respond with 301 (moved permanently).

I can't manage how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself:

```
regex('/foo') -> { set(attribute='%{o,Location}', value='/bar'); response-code(301); }
```